# How do you put full stacks of items in creative mode in the Windows 10 edition of minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Any idea how to do this in Windows 10 edition?  I have tried the hover method along with middle clicking and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

This is already done for you. What confuses most people is that the 10 inventory slots that are always available only show 1 of the item that you are holding, no matter the amount that you actually have.

So, so Items are already full stacks if they are gotten from the creative inventory.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that you can right click on the block you want 64 of in the menu and it picks up 64.

Comment: I think that’s for Java

Answer (score 0):

Middle Click to pick up a full stack. Middle click to place a full stack. Hold middle click and drag to fill a chest full stacks.